# Why my link in the head tag moved to the body?

Tags: php, hyperlink, manifest, head

I don't understand how this happen.
In my index.php, i require the page header.php :

`<?php require("view/viewHeader.php");`

Which contains this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>Mon systeme</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
```

So how i get this on the final page ?

[link outside the head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy28x.png)

The index.php has 165 lines, so i show you the beginning of the switch where the require call the viewHeader.php :

```
switch ($action) {
    case 'ajout':
        $menuTitre = "Ajout";
        require("view/viewHeader.php");
        require("view/viewMenuEnTete.php");
        require("view/viewAjout.php");
        require("view/viewFooter.php");
        break;
```

Yes in the source it is alright

```
<div id="debug">ACTION: string(5) "ajout"
<br/>RECH: NULL
<br/><hr />POST<br/>array(1) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(5) "ajout"
}
<hr /></div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>Mon systeme</title>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
```

But the manifest is not detected. I thought there were a problem with the head mixed up.

I get rid of the small div in top, but it doesn't change anything :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>Mon systeme</title>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
```

Comment: Please show us `index.php`. From your question I don't understand if you have a `header.php` _in addition to_ `viewHeader.php`. If you have both, then please share `header.php` too.

Comment: This screenshot is from the chrome dev tools > elements tab. This will show an altered version of the document where the browser has already tried to fix tag nesting errors. Check out the original page source instead

Comment: The HTML output suggests you have some divs before `<html>` even starts, so that might mess with things.

Comment: I get rid of that div before the html, the source seems okay, but the manifest is still not detected :(